# How to explain the behavior of this code?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```js
v = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  v.push(i);
}

function f(a1, a2) {
  v.shift();
}
v.sort(f);
console.log(v);
```

I think that `v` will delete itself many times and output a short array such as `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]` if the `sort()` compares 10 times.

But the output of Chrome and Firefox are both an array from 0 to 19.

Why? I believe the `shift()` has indeed executed.

Comment: The behavior could be undefined and different depending on the sorting implementation used by your chosen browser. Your sorting function doesn't [fulfill all of the properties it should](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description).

Comment: @AKX doing `console.log(v)` inside the function `f` actually shows that the/an array is being shifted though, yet the original array is unaltered. Which array is getting truncated here? [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w75uvjp1/)

Comment: @DarkBee I would say `Array.prototype.sort` creates a copy of the array `this` and overwrites `this` at the end.

Comment: Which seems odd, because it [should return a *reference*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to the same array?

Comment: It overwrites it element-wise. The reference is correct. `Array.prototype.sort` needs a temporary container for the sort process. The original array isn't modified while sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.sort) of `Array#sort` (which, by the way, can operate on non-Arrays) specifies that sorting be done by

- computing the sorted order into an internal `sortedList`
- replacing the original entries in the target object from that sorted list

which explains why the original array can be mutated (to no effect) in the comparator, but after the comparator has been run to figure out the sorted order, `Array#sort` will replace the items into it from the internal `sortedList`.

Comment: Dose it mean that the array v do changes every time, but at last it is assigned to a copy of its original state because the sort() actually performs on this copy but dose nothing to it?

Comment: @picasso Kind of, yes – the internals of `v` get replaced after all of the sorts are done.